# XenServer xe CLI on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, xen

Is there a port of the XenServer/XCP [xe](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XCP_Command_Line_Interface) command-line tool to Mac OS X? Or, alternately, if this tool is open-source, what's the easiest way to get access to the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's available on OS X.

It looks like the source is available.  In theory it should be available from here:

> http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Repositories

but I had a look around and did not find references to the `xe` tool source.

The Ubuntu package search page shows you can get it from Ubuntu:

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xcp-xe
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xen-api/xen-api_1.3.2.orig.tar.gz